# Determining if a specific proline is cis or trans in the protein?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins

While peptide bonds usually adopt the *trans* conformation, peptide bonds to proline can exist in either *cis* or *trans* conformation. The isomerization between *cis* and *trans* is slow, and has been shown to be the rate-limiting step in folding of certain proteins.

What methods can be used to determine the conformation of a specific proline in a protein?

Answer (score 6):

> Sarkar et al.(2007) Proline cis-trans Isomerization Controls Autoinhibition of a Signaling Protein. *Molecular Cell* **25**, 413–426 (DOI 10.1016/j.molcel.2007.01.004), available [here](http://chem.rutgers.edu/~babis/Publications/Sarkar_Molcell.pdf).

The authors report on the interactions between two SH3 domains of the Crk adaptor protein. Basically they find that the linker which tethers these two domains contains a proline which interconverts between the *cis* and *trans* conformations, and that this interconversion determines the interaction between the two domains. They follow isomerisation by using [NMR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_magnetic_resonance_spectroscopy_of_proteins).

*Cis-trans* peptidyl-prolyl isomerization is a subtle change, and I don't think that you will find a way of following it in a specific protein that is simpler than this, unfortunately.

Comment: i'd agree - the most common method is to determine the structure